# Loop is not working inside python when called from Node js using Cucumber and child process

Tags: python, node.js, cucumber, spawn, revitpythonshell

class main:

```
 async def MasterPool(Size,Assay_PoolSize,TubeID,MasterPoolID,MPSize):


     x=12
     #await time.sleep(10000)
     i=0
     z = Lis(Size,Assay_PoolSize,TubeID)
     t=int(MPSize)-1
     print(t)


     while i==0:
             j = len(os.listdir(r'C:\Test'))
             print(j)

             if j==0:
                 print("MasterPoolInProgress")
                 with open(r'C:\Users\Katyald\Documents\MasterPool\MAS (1).pol','r') as file:
                     data = file.readlines()
                 with open(r'C:\Test\stats.pol', 'w') as f:
                     for i, line in enumerate(data,0):
                         if "Pool Size:" in line:
                             f.writelines("Pool Size: {}\n".format(MPSize))
                         else:       
                             if "Master Pool ID:" in line:
                                 f.writelines("Master Pool ID:{}\n".format(MasterPoolID))
                                 for i in range (0,int(MPSize)):
                                     f.writelines(z[i]+ "\n")

                             else:

                                 f.write(data[i])
                 break
           main.MasterPool(int(sys.argv[1]),str(sys.argv[2]),str(sys.argv[3]),str(sys.argv[4]),int(sys.argv[5]))
```

I am trying to create a e2e automation test case where creation of data is part of the test script. Test Data creation i have written in python which i wanted to use it with the cucumber framework.

I am using Cucumber with typescript, One of the step in that is to create test data for which it calls the above python script using spawn in one of the method which is called in the step defination.

Use Case:
1. Create 4 files in a folder.
2. Check that above files got deleted(In real time testing the files gets deleted as the tool which reads these hl7 files deletes it after reading.)
3. Once deleted then create another file in another directory
4. Check the above file is deleted.
5. Open the UI
6. Validate data on the UI.

The flow ends abruptly showing as test completed with one scenario passed but only the creation of 4 files happens and  the rest of the logic does not work.
When I am executing the above python script through python then it is working as expected but not with the spawn.

One general behavior that i saw is when i am trying to call the loop in python from spawn then it is working till value of 15K and after that it does not work

Comment: The code used for calling the python script through spawn    const path = require('path')
const {spawn} = require('child_process')
 function runScript(){
   console.log("Method going to start")
  return spawn('python', [
    "-u", 
    './Python_TestData/MasterPoolCreation/Sample.py',
    "[4,WnV-4,mks,tk,4]",
  ]);
}
const subprocess = runScript();
subprocess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(`data:${data}`);
  });
  subprocess.on('close', () => {
    console.log("Closed");
  });

Comment: any kind of suggestion will be helpful?